# My print statement wont print my variable in my while loop

Tags: java, printing, while-loop

I have a block of code and I'm trying to make it so it counts down from 10, and prints it after 1 second, but nothing in the while loop will work. Any suggestions? (No errors or tips are popping up in Eclipse IDE)

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int timer = 10;
        while (timer>10) {
            System.out.println(timer);
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            timer = timer - 1;

        }
        System.out.println("Blast Off!");
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

look at your condition in while loop and a timer value:

```
int timer = 10;
while (timer>10) {
```

You set timer to 10. `timer > 10` is never met.

Comment: oops. I didn't notice it said timer>10. Thanks :D

Answer (score 0):

You set timer to 10, meaning that the program inside
`while (timer>10)` will never gets executed.

I think you want `while (timer > 0)` instead

Comment: Thank you. I didn't notice the while loop was set up wrong. :)

Answer (score 0):

You should correct your timer condition to below :

```
while (timer>0)
```

Comment: Didn't notice the while loop was set up wrong. Thanks :)